# Resetting a configuration object to "factory settings"

Tags: entities, 8, configuration

My module defines a configuration entity (specifically a BBCode tag macro with a template) that can be created and edited with a web form.

It can also be created by other modules using a `config/install/xbbcode.tag.*.yml` file - and of course those objects can also be edited and deleted.

Is there a way to access and recreate the original version of a config object that has been edited, without having to reinstall the whole module? I like the flexibility of customizing these templates, but users need to be able to  restore the factory settings somehow.

Comment: You can use YamlDiscovery to search for that yaml configuration file

Comment: You can create a second configuration entity original.xcode.tag.* that is only created when the xcode.tag entity is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core does not provide such an API, not in a way that is easy to use.

There is a contrib module that provides this, but it's probably too complicated to rely on for a specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about this for a while, the solution may be to add a special "editable" flag on user-created objects, and block the update/delete operations on everything else with an entity access handler.

A custom "clone" operation could then be used to create an editable copy of the object, leaving the original unchanged.